# How to match map/dbg symbols file to delphi-written process

Tags: delphi, symbols, dump

I have a map file created by delphi compiler and I need to use it to analyze DMP file.
I converted the map file to dbg file, using [Map2dbg](https://code.google.com/p/map2dbg/).

The problem is that the process has a different signeture then the symbols.
I tried to use chkmatch to match the signeture, but I'm getting:

`Error: Debug information not found in the executable`

I guess this is because it is a delphi process.

Does anyone know how to match the signatures?

Comment: I've successfully loaded a .dmp file into WinDbg with a .dbg file created by map2dbg (http://capnbry.net/blog/?p=18). But it does involve getting a lot of different things exactly right. Mostly though I rely on madExcept for such scenarios. Even for a deadlock scenario you can use madExcept to trace the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a minidumpreader some time ago:
https://asmprofiler.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/MiniDumpReader/ViewMinidump.exe (old link)
https://github.com/andremussche/asmprofiler/tree/master/Releases/ViewMinidump.exe (new link)

It is written in Delphi with jclDebug.pas so it supports all delphi debug symbols.
And because of this it has line number support (which map2dbg or tds2pdb don't have).

Note: I haven't made map2dbg or tds2pdb myself, just hosting it so other can easily find it

Comment: https://github.com/andremussche/asmprofiler/tree/master/Releases